# Any documentation for the package subnets-resolver?

Tags: python, pypi

I am a new user of python and would like to try [subnets-resolver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subnets-resolver). However, I can`t find the documentation of this package. Can someone point me to it?

Comment: I can't find the docs either, but the source is at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subnets-resolver. It's pretty easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are out of luck. Google does not bring anything up, and the code contains no docstrings (quite unpythonic). You will have to figure it out yourself. You could write a documentation in the process and and make it available for others though.